# CakePHP 2.x and Atlassian Crowd

Tags: cakephp, single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

I'm rolling out a number of cakePHP-based internal tools and would like to leverage our Crowd instance for user management. Has anyone successfully integrated Crowd with Cake? Do I treat it like any other LDAP provider?